# How to do a git install with constraints in a requirements file?

Tags: pip, python-packaging

I have a package I want to install with a constraints file. How can you specify constraints file with a git URL in a `requirements` file?

ex. what I have `-e git+https://....#egg=package` I want to add constraints as well. Using `-e git+https://....#egg=package --constraints constraints.txt` doesn't seem to work as there are still package conflicts that happen.